# Cannondale CAAD12 headset proprietary or replaceable?

Tags: headset, cannondale

Just wondering if the headsets used in the CAAD12 frames include replaceable bearing cups, or if the cups are integrated into the frame (non-replaceable). I'm also wondering if the headsets are standard, and therefore replaceable with a good aftermarket set?
Thanks.

Comment: The factory spec sheet states caad12 headset. Photos of the headtube show what appears to be a standard integrated headset.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The CAAD 12 uses sealed cartridge bearings which are replaceable and not proprietary.

You shouldn't need many special tools to service the headset bearings, especially if they are new - you should be able to tap them out and remove the necessary parts with a screwdriver or wedge.

However, if you are asking the question because you are concerned with home serviceability, you *will* need a press to do any work on Cannondale's BB30 and BB30a (CAAD12) bottom brackets, which need service more than the headset.  There are videos out there of people doing it without a proper press, but it's risky.

Below are some pictures of a sealed headset bearing removal, similar to the CAAD.  Also, there is a picture of a makeshift press that you could use for servicing the bottom bracket, if you don't want to spend an exorbitant amount on the park tool BB30 press.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Bottom Bracket Removal Tool and Press:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I don't plan to do it myself. Just considering buying a CAAD12 and want to know that I can get parts replaced when they wear out.

Comment: @NorthKrimsly I have a CAAD 10 disc myself and love it. I think you'll be happy if you end up making the purchase.

Comment: Great update! The only amendment I would include is that with the CAAD12 is has a carbon steerer (unlike the above images), and as such you really need to use a torque wrench to tighten the stem bolts, to eliminate the risk of cracking the fork.

Answer (score 0):

Its a standard headset (if such a thing exists) I believe its an IS42/28.6 upper and IS47/33? lower.

These are easy to replace even at home. Don't require a bearing press, or any other specialist tools (with the possible exception of a torque wrench). They drop into the cups in the frame and then use the tension from the top cap as pre-load to stop movement.